# Concurrent transactions changing application name with trigger reading it

Tags: postgresql

We have an application using same session/connection for. I wanted to know what happens when 2 operations are called in the "exact same time". There is a trigger for the DELETE reading out the application name.

Is there a possibility that the trigger of one call uses the application name changed by the other call?

```
first call
BEGIN;
SET SESSION application_name='Web-App - userId: 31';
DELETE ...;
--Here fires the trigger reading application name
COMMIT;

second concurrent call
BEGIN;
SET SESSION application_name='Web-App - userId: 32';
DELETE ...;
--Here fires the trigger reading application name
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Postgres doesn't allow concurrent transactions within a session. If your application is sharing connections between threads, it's almost certainly broken.

Comment: Okay thank you. In conclusion that means 'no' as answer. The application name can't be changed by another call because they can't be concurrent/parallel. The session/connection is busy at the time, so no second call can be done. It has to wait for the connection to accept transactions again and therefore transactions are handled one after another. Are my assumptions right?

Comment: Not quite. The *server* has no concept of concurrent transactions within a session. That doesn't stop a client from trying to send them anyway. But from the server's perspective, it will just be a jumbled mess. At best you'll get weird errors, at worst you'll trash your database. If you really need to share a session between threads, then it's up to your application to make the calls sequentially. But it sounds like what you really want is probably a connection pool.